# Hiring Contractors for Lead Generation

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, subcontracting

I want to hire a few contractors to help get leads for my business.

I am planning on paying the contractors **commission only**. (*i.e. I get $X in sales from there referral and they get a fixed % of $X.*)

Of course, the goal to get as many new and repeat clients as possible. ***My issue is this:***

How do I make the agreement fair for my contractors and give them strong incentives to work hard without having to continue paying for returning business from previously referred clients?

### **There are three basic situations:**

1.**Individual one-time or first-time sale** - Obviously, I will pay for this.

2.**Repeat business from the same client** - I want to avoid having to pay recurring commissions on.

3.**Bulk Sale** - I will pay for this even if it involves previous clients assuming the contractor initiates/prompts the sale and the quantity is above a specified amount.

Comment: No, customers will see no difference. I'm talking about what I pay the contractors who bring me customers.

Comment: Wouldn't it merely be a one time finder's fee?

Comment: Yes I guess so. I'm looking for what is the common practice and legal terms to use in the contract.

Answer (score 1):

I've done been offering incentives to individuals and companies that refer me business for years now and I always use a floating commission in order to keep my referral network motivated and happy. I give them 12.5% **of the net** for the first time they refer me a client and substantially less for future referrals of the same customer. Once upon a time someone referred me to a contract at Microsoft, that's a huge company, obviously. So, the first time, I gave him 12.5%, then a few months later, I was referred to a different department within M$FT, for which I gave him 6%. Being a web/software development company, this was a recurring fee. You'll definitely want to code a management system to keep track of this information & perhaps even initiate the payments to your referrers. I find that as long as you're making a decent profit, the most important thing that you can do is to keep your referral network motivated to sell for you and not the other guy.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a template form for your commission's contracts. Typically with a little due diligence, you can find what you need.

I use [RocketLawyer.com](https://www.rocketlawyer.com/document/commission-agreement.rl) for most of my legal documents and haven't had a single issue finding what I've needed.